# Регулярные выражения JAVA - жадные и ленивые кватификаторы

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Пример строки:

```
String example = "   (22 ;   325)   ";
```

Общий вид строки:

```
String pattern = "\\s*(\\s*\\d+\\s*;\\s*\\d+\\s*)\\s*";
```

Два числа в круглых скобках, разделенные между собой точкой с запятой. Количество пробелов между символами произвольное.

Возможно ли получить массив из 2 строк: 22 и 325, используя лишь одно регулряное выражение и метод `split()` ?

```
final String REGEX = "\\s*\\(*\\s*;*\\s*]";
```

Я рассчитывал что такое выражение подойдет как для:

```
//s+//(
```

, так и для:

```
//s+;//s+
```

и для:

```
//s+)//s+`
```

Но оно работает напротив - максимально некорректно и ищет, судя по всему, самое минимальное совпадение

Другими словами данный перечень конкретных примеров :

```
(
```

окруженная с двух сторон любым количеством пробелов, либо не окружена ни одним пробелом.

```
)
```

то же самое

```
;
```

то же самое

нужно свести к одной регулярке. При этом, между ними идут числа в любой форме записи(2, 2.2f, 2.22e-22)

Comment: единственный рабочий вариант пока что - написать через оператор | но вариант этот корявый

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если удалить пробелы и скобки, то хватит сплита по разделителю:

```
String example = "   (22 ;   325)   ";
String[] items = example.replaceAll("[ ()]", "").split(";");

System.out.println(Arrays.asList(items)); // [22, 325]
```

Comment: Вопрос решен, спасибо вам) Теперь попробую адаптировать этот подход к реальной задаче, которая несколько сложнее

Answer (score 0):

Хммм... Краткость - сестра таланта. Попробуйте моё выражение:

```
([0-9])\w+
```

Берёт числа, разделённые любым символом, отличным от цифры

Comment: числа наоборот должны оставаться, а всё лишнее отброситься сплитом. Причем самые общие схемы вроде //W не подойдут, я пример написал в общем виде. на самом деле могут быть числа в любом виде(в т.ч. флоат, например 25.5f,  научная форма записи 1.1e-21 и др.)